# How long is a KERBEROS/SPNEGO ticket valid for?

Tags: kerberos, spnego

Scenario:

1) you are implementing a website/webserver that supports SSO (SPNEGO). 
2) A client connects to you and provides you a ticket which is valid, so access is granted to the client

Question  - At this point, should I implement some mechanism such as a cookie that allows for the client to no longer generate tickets (Storing some value that can be cached client side and used for subsequent calls) ? How long/how many requests can I honor the same spnego token? I tried finding the answer for the second question and could not find an answer.... What is the "MAXLIFE" of a token that you can generate  for a SPNEGO token?

Answer (score 2):

The first question/answer clearly depends on your usecase. If you have a website with a browser, a session cookie, e.g. `JSESSIONID`, is the way to go. If this is some library, it has to support cookies. Thoughly, ticket generation is extremely fast.

Second question: Do not fiddle with the tickets. They cannot be reused and will throw an exception: this is a replay. Pass those tokens to SSPI/GSS-API and throw the context away when the auth is completed. As soon as the server nags you again, create a new context and send a new token.

By default, a ticket is valid for 10 hours in Active Directory but this can be changed by the admin. Use `kerbtray.exe` on Windows or `klist` on Unix to see the lifetime of your tickets.